# How to make a click event for a tag in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to implement swiping feature on my website for the photo slider.
I figured out the swipe function. However, I am trying to figure out how to show the next or previous photo and change the indicator of the photo slider together. The best way I can think is clicking a tag. I already have a tags on the right and right side of the photo slider, which I want. But, How can I click that a tag as if I really click that a tag?

This is my code below.

```
var x1; var x2;
$(document).on('mousedown', '.carousel', function() {
    x1 = event.pageX;
});
$(document).on('mouseup', '.carousel', function() {
    x2 = event.pageX;

    var id = '#'+$(this).attr('id');

    if(x1 - x2 > 0){
        $(id).children('a[data-slide="next"]').trigger('click');
    } else {
        $(id).children('a[data-slide="prev"]').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

And this doesn't also work.

```
if(x1 - x2 > 0){
    $(id).children('a[data-slide="next"]').click();
} else {
    $(id).children('a[data-slide="prev"]').click();
}
```

Comment: Let me get this straight, you have different links for each action, right? One in the left with the `data-slide="prev"` attribute and one in the right with `data-slide="next"`, right?

Comment: Yes, I have two a tags which have 'data-slide="next"' and 'data-slide="prev"' respectively.

Comment: Write down the HTML structure this function is supposed to work on so we can help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call:

```js
$(id).children('a[data-slide="next"]').click();
```

see: https://api.jquery.com/click/#click

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write it down too. And I've tried this already and It doesn't work. It seems like it is an event listener. I mean it runs when you click the actual a tag and then you implement something inside.

hover, keyup, keydown, mouseenter, etc 

those functions are for event, I guess. When 'those' occurs then you can implement something inside.

    $('div').click(function(){
       // todo
    });

like this.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to attach a event handler for each attribute and do your logic inside each one. Also, it would be much easier if either your image ids were sequential, like, 1-2-3 or if you set them in a separate attribute in your link, like `data-id` or something.

```
$(document).on("click", "[data-slide=next]", function (event) {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
});

$(document).on("click", "[data-slide=prev]", function (event) {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
});
```

Comment: No, This is not what I want. I want to change when I swipe. not clicking the a tag. I want to change the pictures when I swipe. I don't click the a tag directly, I want to run it when I swipe.